# Display explicit interface members in a propertygrid?

Tags: c#, propertygrid, explicit-interface

Suppose we have this code:

```
interface myInterface { long Test { set; get; } }

class myInterfaceImp : myInterface
{
    long myInterface.Test { get; set; }
}
```

and in our form, we set the propertygrid:

```
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new myInterfaceImp();
```

Unfortunately, **PropertyGrid** do not show explicit interface implementation.
What should we do?

Comment: Could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532719/cant-show-class-with-interface-properties-in-propertygrid

Comment: Change your code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create some kind of "View" object that knows how to display your myInterface implementation.